# Do ArrayBlockingQueue wrapper methods need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads, one that dispatches messages and another that parses them. Simple, common. I use `ArrayBlockingQueue` for synchronization, but don't want the dispatcher to directly access workers message queue - I use a wrapper. The question is if the setter should be declared `synchronized`.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable{
    protected final ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> messages = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>(16);

    public synchronized void putMessage(ByteBuffer msg) throws InterruptedException{
        messages.put(ByteBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the setter? Is it putMessage()? Then it's not a setter.

Comment: Oh that. Will edit the question.

Comment: @MozenRath the queue object is final, it will not change. Not its contents:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `putMessage` method would have to be synchronized if only one thread at a time needed to access a non-thread-safe shared state inside this method (or would have to make several modifications on a shared state atomically).

All the method does is to call a method on an `ArrayBlockingQueue`, which is designed precisely to be accessed concurrently by several threads.

The method doesn't need to be synchronized.